# Python: Fastest way to generate unique lists from a range of numbers

Tags: python, combinations

Im trying to generate 5,760,000 unique lists, i.e. no repeating elements in each list and no one list is the same. Each list will have 24 numbers, ranging from 1 to 10,000. Order matters so for example (1,2,3) and (3,2,1) will be considered unique.

I tried the following just to check if `random.sample` gives me unique lists out of the box but it has been going on forever:

```
import random
mainlist = []

for i in range(1,5760001):
    r=random.sample(range(1,10000),24)
    if r not in mainlist:
        mainlist.append(r)
```

How can I best solve this

Comment: You can use ```iterations.combinations```

Comment: ```[l for m in range(5760000) for m in itertools.combinations(list(range(1,10000)),24)]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with your approach is that `mainlist` is a list, meaning that `if r not in mainlist` will take more and more time. Change it to a `set` (and the actual elements to `tuple` so they are hashable), then the lookup will be much faster. In fact, you can just drop the `in` check, as a `set` can not have duplicates in the first place. Also note that your `for` loop will just try 5760000 numbers, but does (theoretically<sup>1</sup>) not ensure that the list contains that many elements in the end, so better use `while`.

```
mainset = set()
while len(mainset) < 5760000:
    mainset.add(tuple(random.sample(range(1, 10001), 24)))
```

For 5760000 numbers, this will still take a while, but the complexity should be down from O(n²) to O(n). If the sample-size approaches the maximum number of possible combinations, this will also get dramatically slow as you get more and more clashes, but for your numbers this should not be a problem.<sup>1</sup> In fact, you might just as well just use a list comprehension without any checks:<sup>2</sup>

```
mainset = [random.sample(range(1, 10001), 24) for _ in range(5760000)]
```

---

Alternatively, you can generate *all* those combinations by combining `itertools.combinations` with `permutations`,<sup>3</sup> but of course those will be massively too many<sup>2</sup> in your case. (Seriously, do *not* run this with *your* numbers!)

```
>>> from itertools import combinations, permutations
>>> nums = range(5)
>>> [p for c in combinations(nums, 3) for p in permutations(c)]
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), ... 57 more ... (4, 3, 2)]
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> In fact, the number of possible combinations is so immensely higher<sup>2</sup> than 5.7M that you could just use a list and *drop* that `in` check and most probably still would have not a single clash.

<sup>2)</sup> Just to put it into perspective: There are [(n over k)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) combinations, each having k! permutations. For *n=10000* and *k=24*, this makes *1.56e72* combinations and *6.2e23* permutations *per* combination for a total of *9.72e95* possible elements. Comparing that to the meager *5.7e6* in your sample, the probability for a collision is practically *zero*.

<sup>3)</sup> Or just [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) with 2nd parameter.

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely go with the first option of creating the set. The itertools option was taking longer and kept freezing my computer. But yes as you mentioned it unfortunately still takes a while to get results but way faster than my attempt. I wonder if doing the computation through cython will speed things up significantly. Will give a try

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for any lists satisfying those criteria, this will give you a generator for the 5760000 lexicographically earliest unique lists of size 24; calling `list()` on mainlist will put the list into memory.

```py
from itertools import permutations, islice
mainlist = islice(permutations(range(1, 10000), 24), 5760000)
```

For uniformly random lists, on the other hand, tobias's answer gives the solution. If speed or memory is a concern, using a generator, such as those given by islice or starmap, is recommended with large datasets.

```py
mainlist = starmap(random.sample, repeat((range(1, 10000), 24), 5760000))
```

Comment: The `random.shuffle` should not be necessary, elements in `sample` are not ordered by occurrance in the original list.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks, just fixed that. Looking at the Python3 docs, it appears that itertools.permutations has similar behavior, so using itertools.combinations is also unnecessary.

Comment: You are right, wasn't even aware `permutations` _had_ a second parameter! :-D

Comment: Got it, cheers. The itertools permutations was super fast takes about a second compared to `random.sample` which goes almost 2 minutes. Unfortunately for my use case and as you said, the permutations even though unique, dont look random enough due to a pattern eg 1,2,3,4,5 followed by 1,2,3,4,6